# Are there any Code coverage tool for Universal Windows Package apps

Tags: code-coverage, uwp

I am building a Universal Windows Package apps for Win10 and would like code coverage done for it but the Visual Studio Enterprise edition doesn't support code coverage for Windows Store or Windows Phone apps. Are there any tools out there, that would do code coverage. dotCover by Jetbrains doesnt work with UWP either

Comment: Have you tried OpenCover? see to https://opencover.codeplex.com/

Comment: UWP allows multiple languages:  C++, C#, VB, JS.   Do you want code coverage for all these langauges or just C# (which you hint at by talking about dotCover)?.

Comment: I've tried using dotCover by JetBrains and it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: OpenCover doesn't seem to support UWP either https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/890

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is no - there is no code coverage support yet for UWP apps in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Any plans to get this done soon? I sometimes feel like Microsoft doesn't give UWP enough love. It really should have all the tooling that other platforms have.

Comment: Is this available in visual studio 2019?

Comment: Doesn't seems so, VS2019 Enterprise 16.5.5 just spits out "Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran.. blaablaa.. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731". Would be an improvement from Microsoft that VS would give a bit more hint what went wrong, e.g "Project type is not supported" or similar would be more helpful, but no. I think Microsoft has abandoned UWP and everything should be NetCore for now on.